# When do special features get unlocked in Gran Turismo 5?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I want to find out when special features like damage, better AI, weather effects etc gets unlocked in GT5, but the searches I performed just turned up guesses or rumours. Is there a definitive answer for how GT5 unlocks work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no "unlock" for features. Damage is in, and can be turned on in some modes. Weather effects appear in certain races (marked "change weather/time" in selections). Some higher level and special races have rules like no skid recovery, but no new magic will appear otherwise.

Software updates constantly provide more features, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the various race types in a-spec mode are unlocked when you reach certain levels.

The extreme series is at lv25 if I recall, and the super red bull challenge thing is at lv30.

There is a fuller list of unlocks over here, http://www.cheatcc.com/ps3/granturismo5cheatscodes.html

Comment: Extreme's lower than that, I'm pretty sure. I think it's 15.